# Copiar conteudo de uma tabela para outra

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela, uma chamada "cars" com as colunas
carID | image

outra tabela chamada "pictures" com as colunas
picID | InName

Gostaria de copiar todas as fotos da tabela "cars" coluna "image" para a tabela "picture" coluna "InName"

Tentei seguir um codigo colocado ja aqui , o codigo funcionou sem erro mas o resultado foi:

> "Nenhuma linha alterada"

```
UPDATE picture pc 
INNER JOIN cars AS c 
ON c.image = pc.ImName 
SET pc.ImName = c.image;
```

Comment: Como é feito o relacionamento entre as tabelas `cars` e `pictures`?

Comment: Basta fazer um `INSERT ... SELECT ...`. Se as tabelas não são relacionadas, não tem porque fazer join, muito menos fazer um update para **inserir** registros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nâo precisa muito para perceber que o código que escreveu não faz sentido para aquilo que deseja fazer.

```
UPDATE picture pc 
INNER JOIN cars AS c 
ON c.image = pc.ImName 
SET pc.ImName = c.image;
```

Utilizou o `UPDATE` sendo que deseja **inserir** novos registros; fez um `JOIN` em tabelas não relacionadas (ou pelo menos você não comentou que existe uma chave estrangeira relacionando-as e, se existe, ela foi ignorada no código); fez a condição `c.image = pc.ImName` sendo que a imagem não existe em `picture`, então nunca a condição será satisfeita.

> *Gostaria de copiar todas as fotos da tabela "cars" coluna "image" para a tabela "picture" coluna "InName"*

Como você quer **selecionar** dados de uma tabela e **inserir** em outra, terá que utilizar o `SELECT` e o `INSERT`.

```
INSERT INTO picture (InName)
SELECT image FROM cars
```

Isso selecionará todos os registros de `cars`, apenas a coluna `image` e salvará na tabela `picture`. Se não precisar de todos os registros, basta adicionar uma cláusula `WHERE` no seu `SELECT`.

Comment: Muitissimo Obrigado,

Voce me salvou muitas horas de trabalho, usando seu codigo consegui colocar todos as foto com suas respectivas IDs, ignorando os Id que nao possuem foto.


INSERT INTO pictures (ImgName, CarID)
SELECT Image, CarID FROM cars 
WHERE Image <>''